# What 80s alien movie has a man possessed by a creature via the back of his neck?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

What's the title of this a late 80s or early 90s movie?

The title is the name of whatever the main character turns into. All I can remember is this man unknowingly being taken over by this thing that goes into the back of his neck. He then has a suit and has to fight 4 aliens who landed on Earth.

The aliens all look different and can talk, they have different voices and personalities.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds enough like [The Guyver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guyver) (eponymous strange artifact that latches onto the body, Bio-Armour, Aliens, etc) that it might be worth for you to check.

It's early nineties, not eightes, but 1991 still sounds close.

[image: The Guyver]

Comment: Shame this never got confirmed as the answer. A good movie, even with its numerous flaws. The sequel, though, (Dark Hero) was a fantastic low-budget Guyver movie.

Answer (score 0):

For another lump-on-neck horror movie, try The Manitou (1978).

Comment: Does it involve the person with the lump on the neck fighting aliens?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe other ways in which this movie might be a match?  Does the person with the lump have to fight aliens?  This answer needs more details; you should read [answer].

Answer (score -1):

The Puppet Masters like a stingray thingy on the back.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to clarify whether it matches the other details mentioned in the question? I.e. did the man have a suit, and did he fight four aliens?